# SystemStackError - stack level too deep: Using metaprograming with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

I need to receive all abilities for current_user in :json for my backbone app. So the firs idea was to add some think like this:

```
def receive_user_abilities # we will return onty hash for works and tasks
    w = Work.accessible_by(current_ability).map { |w| w = {type: 'Work', id: w.id}) }
    t = Task.accessible_by(current_ability).map { |t| t = {type: 'Task', id: t.id}) }
    render json:  t + w # returs merged hash
end
```

But both line are particular the same, and I decided to user some metaprograming magic. So my solution was to create new helper, include it to my controller, and pass *arg to newly created module(helper) method. Here it is:

```
 module AbilitiesHelper
  def receive_abilities_for *classes
    classes.inject([]) { |res, klass| res + eval( klass.to_s.capitalize + '.accessible_by(current_ability).map { |element| element = ({type: ' + klass.to_s.capitalize + ', id: element.id }) }') }
  end
end
```

and here is new call from controller

```
def receive_user_abilities
    render json: receive_abilities_for(:work, :task) # returs merged hash
  end
```

It's basically the same, but for some reason I receive an error `SystemStackError - stack level too deep:`

Where is the error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this approach would be easier?

```
def receive_abilities_for *classes
  classes.inject([]) do |res, klass| 
    res + klass.accessible_by(current_ability).map do |element| 
      element = {type: klass.to_s, id: element.id } 
    end
  end
end
```

And call this method in such way:

```
def receive_user_abilities
  render json: receive_abilities_for(Work, Task)
end
```

Also, as for me, **receive_abilities_for** method isn't metaprogramming. Metaprogramming is defining new methods and classes at runtime (I may be mistaken).

Comment: You are right, but it is fun to use it )) You approach is great to. Thank you

Comment: also, **element = {type: klass.to_s, id: element.id }** line should be replaced with **{type: klass.to_s, id: element.id }**